# What are firmware blobs (from linux-firmware) exactly?

Tags: drivers, kernel, bluetooth, firmware

According to https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Linux_firmware,

> Linux firmware is a package distributed alongside the Linux kernel
> that contains firmware binary blobs necessary for partial or full
> functionality of certain hardware devices. These binary blobs are
> usually proprietary because some hardware manufacturers do not release
> source code necessary to build the firmware itself.

For example, my bluetooth pcie device requires `linux-firmware/qca/htbtfw20.tlv`. Is this a kernel driver? Why the format `.tlv`, and why some are `.bin`? Generally kernel drivers are ELF executables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Many hardware vendors make a secret in how their hardware work. That's why they hide some functions of their devices into closed source blobs. They distribute the blobs with their drivers.

These blobs are not executed by the OS, but are loaded into the hardware. After the blob is loaded, OS can manage the device using some driver.

In case of Bluetooth a generic Linux module, e.g. `btusb`, or `hci_qca` in your case, is used for most of devices. The module detects the device, loads firmware and then it can use the device as any other one.

It doesn't really matter how the file is called. It is chosen by a vendor.

Firmware is not exactly a driver. It is some code executed by a device that allows it to communicate with a driver.

Linux maintainers get firmware from vendors, or their drivers and accumulate the blobs in [linux-firmware git](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git).

Distribution maintainers, like Сanonical, pack this firmware into packages. In case of Ubuntu it is surprisingly `linux-firmware` package. It is made of the kernel linux-frimware git and updated from time to time.

Comment: Thanks. But why isn't the firmware already in the device?

Comment: I think having non-volatile memory is more expensive and flashing a new blob would be more difficult for a user. So it is loaded from the OS on boot.

Comment: Having read only memory makes the device bigger and more expensive than it realistically needs to be. Plus, having the firmware be loaded by the operating system makes firmware updates and fixes much easier (hence why you can do it through your package manager).